# dojo.require not loading in recursive order

Tags: javascript, dojo, cross-domain

I'm trying to move some of my dojo 1.7 codebase online. I've enabled CORS on the server, and local/online files are loaded with `dojo.require`.

While this worked fine for local files, http files would fail to load in recursive order. For example,

```
dojo.registermodulepath("my.path", "http://my.path");
dojo.require(my.path.module1);
dojo.require(my.path.module2);
```

Now, assuming the `module1` file is loaded, and has its own sub-dependencies, `dojo.require` is supposed to load those sub-dependencies first; but I observed that for online files, it goes directly to loading `module2` and breaks the order.

As a result the app won't function. How so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, dependencies at the same "level" (e.g. two `dojo.require` calls in the same module) aren't expected to be order-dependent.  If `module2` really depends on `module1` having been loaded, then `module2` itself should contain a `require` call for `module1`, which would accurately express a recursive dependency.

I would advise against assuming that `dojo.require` operates synchronously - operating under that assumption will break the moment you try to do a cross-domain build, or update to use the loader in proper AMD mode with `async: true`.

Meanwhile, if by "local" you mean filesystem access, it's *highly* recommended to use an actual Web server to run web applications.  Browsers typically operate much more restrictively for file:// URLs, for example blocking XHR.

Comment: Now that I think about it, my "local files" are in fact sent over HTTP as well. It's the server that's local.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure which way to read it.  If you're really talking about modules from 2 HTTP servers, I'd really encourage you to look at updating your code to the AMD format and switching on `async: true` in the loader - at that point you don't need CORS either because the loader operates via script injection, not sync XHR + eval.  The [Introduction to AMD modules](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/index.html) and [Advanced AMD Usage](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/index.html) tutorials are worth a read.

Comment: Problem solved. Turns out all I needed to do was to `dojo.require` those files directly, instead of recursively. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

you could set

```
  <script>
dojoConfig= {
     async: false
};
</script>
```

or in AMD style you could load module2 only after module1 loads